# Installed Xubuntu 13.04 and cannot update to 14.04, can't find server

Tags: xubuntu, internet

Today I installed xubuntu 13.04 and I can't update it to ver. 14.04. I can't install any apps from software center too. When i click "find best server for your location" I can't find any server. But my internet is working. what's wrong?
p.s. Sorry for my english.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I skip over releases when upgrading?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/can-i-skip-over-releases-when-upgrading) or [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

13.04 is End of Life, and no longer supported.  As such, the repository mirrors, the drivers' mirrors, etc. do not have the 13.04 repositories anymore.

The currently supported versions are Precise (12.04), Trusty (14.04), and Utopic (14.10), with a new release by the end of the month (Vivid, 15.04).  You should be using one of these releases' installers to install your 14.04 rather than trying to update from 13.04 to 13.10 (which is also end of life) to 14.04 (you should also not do that because with each upgrade you run the risk of breaking the operating system).

You should only be using one of thsoe versions, using ISOs obtained from http://releases.ubuntu.com or one of the CD image mirrors.